# Report chart filters and filter conditions

Tags: visualforce, reporting, reports-api, report-chart

I am using a visualforce page on which i am displaying a reportchart using `analytics:reportchart`.

I am specifying the 2 filter conditions in the `filter` attribute.

```
<apex:page>
  <analytics:reportChart developerName="AnalyticsTest"  filter="[{column:'SALES', operator: 'greaterThan', value:'350000000'}, {column:'RATING', operator: 'equals', value:'Warm'} ]"></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

I am looking for a way in which i can change the filter condition logic. Currently, it appears to be defaulting to `1 AND 2`. What needs to be done in case i want to change it to **1 OR 2**?

Is anybody aware on how to do this?

Comment: With the built in component? Not possible. You could recreate it using the Analytics API.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear this isn't possible using `<analytics:reportChart>`. However, depending on your goal here you may be able to achieve the same results through different means.

I set up a test report with a basic OR filter, when I do the describe for the report (`/services/data/v37.0/analytics/reports/<reportId>`) the filters and filter logic are returned separately which would imply that for what you're doing to work you'd need an additional attribute on the `reportChart` component to pass that in.

```
"reportBooleanFilter" : "1 OR 2",
"reportFilters" : [ {
  "column" : "ACCOUNT.NAME",
  "isRunPageEditable" : true,
  "operator" : "equals",
  "value" : "Test 1"
}, {
  "column" : "ACCOUNT.NAME",
  "isRunPageEditable" : true,
  "operator" : "equals",
  "value" : "Test 2"
} ],
```